# Remove non function properties from generic object and use that in a generic class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class, that can take a version of itself (without any functions) to be used as a way to construct the object.

Within that class I have a generic object property, the intention is that the class can also contain a generic object provided by the callee so they can also have type safety. The problem is I think I have something slightly wrong with my understanding of generics.

```
TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.
```

My assumption here is that Test< T > should always contain a 'genericObject' no matter the type. But I think typescript becomes confused.

```
/**
Get all non function property names
 */
export type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

/**
 * Pick each of the properties by name
 */
export type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

/**
 *
 */
export default class Test<T> {
  genericObject?: T;
  typedObject: object;

  constructor(block: Test<NonFunctionProperties<T>>) {
    // Store typed object
    this.typedObject = { ...block.typedObject };
    this.genericObject = { ...block.genericObject };
  }
}

/**
 * Usage
 */
type CustomType = {
  num: number;
  str: string;
  ignoredFn: () => void;
};

const myTestObject = new Test<NonFunctionProperties<CustomType>>({
  genericObject: {
    num: 5,
    str: "string",
  },
  typedObject: {
    num: 5,
    str: "string",
  },
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgHEFMBcAICGAbZ8B2B7d8BmBXdAY1gEtt4AHAJ00umtgE8NEBbaAZ3HhGHGgAPSpkbxm9eADlsAMUIly6AAq16jJlPZcAPABUAfPAC88AN494AbQDS8UjgDW0Jplzw9AXQBcH25-ghWGh0ABNOeHliMgoAfgxoADcGeF8bAG5wAF8rZ1d3L0zwUAheeGVSIkdAxCIAC3g3cTroKjUGMi54ACMWdG0ePgFhUQQJVpl0KMVsVToO0l1DE3LKx30AGmk5BRiVdo0tDk59AwMiksHB-iERMVDoXER8ZAQiZEROCL0uWFPzSwAcxCDEqAHlugAraAkWK+PSZeDiJj0UIQ6EkXyYKEw2BFJFEbCcWDUfAkUQACm6yEwVV8k2mezm6k6Jx+xNOBgAlACkUjgMB4ABlWCiVrjUKNHEkSxI2B1UicAB0EvRuJWZngSu11NpjhVKOgaOlCCyiL58sVSuB6FBRDVJA1Wp1NKq1pB1HBJvgZvgAt4IAYtGo8Ba1GgYEsWWy4GKkbKAFVOIhgddwON4ABhfDEzBsPSGjWWdD4Ni+EtsboMc3E6i+WsOQHm0iArDh0KydC+Ck84xGRKYUihTJm2OE9DE+BsJjs2AOhCmW0Adw8vx0DN2SmZC102dz+cNZwpFiRNrt898J75Fd8AFYNrL4LXfAAiBvoQEvh9IrLf5Goi9eWvUs7z-JFn3gN8SUbL8owfLIuXSIA)

Comment: Just updated now.

Comment: *I'm* confused, why is `block` of type `NonFunctionProperties<Test<T>>` and not `Test<NonFunctionProperties<T>>`?

Comment: And, like, why aren't you doing [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5zedm)?  Is there some reason why `genericObject` is optional? Is there some reason why you are claiming that `genericObject` has all the properties of `T` even though `{...block.genericObject}` probably doesn't?  Help me out here 

Comment: Great spot jcalz - I have just updated the question to reflect that problem

Comment: I'd also be leery of creating a shallow copy of what's passed in. I'd be inclined to make the caller do the copy if appropriate, not least because A) Some objects can't be shallow-copied via spread syntax (`Date`s for instance), B) Any object with nested object/array properties will be copied incorrectly, and C) Any object that relies on logic in its constructor will be copied incorrectly.

Comment: Agree, in this case I considered ensuring that T was forced to extend an interface that provided a copy of the object

Comment: @Asheh - Even that seems overkill unless `Test` itself has some *other* reason for doing a copy.

Comment: To put it into context the entire object tree of class "Test" needs to be serialized to JSON. And just as you have described sometimes with the spread syntax this wont work as desired. I simplified it for this post.

Comment: If you decide to respond to [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015878/remove-non-function-properties-from-generic-object-and-use-that-in-a-generic-cla?noredirect=1#comment130687382_74015878), please mention @jcalz so I'm notified.  Right now I am still confused about what your intentions are and why you're not just giving the `genericObject` property the type `NonFunctionProperties<T>` to begin with.  Or just `T` and deal with serializability some other way?